# Opening a WebSocket connection between Angular 2+ client and Django backend

Tags: python, django, angular, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to open a websocket connection from my angular 2+ app with my Django backend using Django Channels.
I went through this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8
and managed to get everything working with the javascript portion written inline in a Django html template. But I am having issues simply opening a websocket connection when I migrated the front-end chat form to a separate angular 2 app.
Both font-end and backends are hosted locally.

**Front End - Chat Form Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let message of thread.messages">
  <div>{{message.message}}</div>
</div>

<form #formData [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input formControlName="messageInput" #msgInput type="text" class="form-control" id="newMessage" placeholder="Type a message">
  </div>
  <button (click)="onSubmit($event)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**Front End - Chat Form Component**

```
  otherUser: User;
  me: User;
  threadId: number;
  thread: Thread;
  endpoint: string;
  socket: WebSocket;

  form = new FormGroup({
    messageInput: new FormControl("")
  });

  get messageInput() {
    return this.form.get('messageInput');
  }


  getThreadById(id: number) {
    this._chatService.getThreadById(id).subscribe(thread => {
      console.log("response: thread found", thread);
      this.thread = thread;
    },
      error => {
        console.log("error", error);
      });
  }

  getEndpoint() {
    let loc = window.location
    let wsStart = "ws://"
    if (loc.protocol == "https:") {
      wsStart = 'wss://'
    }
    this.endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname;
    return this.endpoint;
  }


  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => { this.threadId = params['id']; });
    if (this.threadId) {
      this.getThreadById(this.threadId);
    }
    this.getEndpoint();
    this.createSocket();
  }

  createSocket() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(this.endpoint);
    console.log("endpoint ", this.endpoint);

    this.socket.onopen = (e) => {
      console.log("open", e);
    }

    this.socket.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log("message", e);
      let chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data);
      this.thread.messages.push(chatDataMsg.message);
    }

    this.socket.onerror = (e) => {
      console.log("error", e);
    }

    this.socket.onclose = (e) => {
      console.log("close", e);
    }

  }

  onSubmit($event) {
    let msgText = this.messageInput.value;
    let finalData = {
      'message': msgText
    };
    let chatMessage: ChatMessage = new ChatMessage(this.thread, this.me, new Date(), msgText);
    this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
    this.form.reset();
  }
```

**Django Backend Project Settings**

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "joole.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
            #"hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')]
        },
    },
}


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['joole-api.herokuapp.com', '.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']
```

**Django Websocket Routing**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.conf.urls import url
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator, OriginValidator
from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r"^messages/(?P<id>[\w.@+-]+)/$", ChatConsumer)
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

**Django Project Urls**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('messages/', include('chat.urls')),
]
```

**Django WebSocket Consumer**

```
import asyncio
import json
from users.models import CustomUser, Employee
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from .models import Thread, ChatMessage


class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("CONNECTED", event)

        thread_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['id']
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(thread_id)
        self.thread_obj = thread_obj
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.send({
            "type": 'websocket.accept'
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("receive", event)
        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg = loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = 'default'
            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.email
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': user.email
            }
            await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)
            # broadcasts the message event to be sent
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text": json.dumps(myResponse)
                }
            )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # send the actual message event
        print("message", event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event["text"]
        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, id):
        return Thread.objects.get(id=id)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat_message(self, me, msg):
        thread_obj = self.thread_obj
        return ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread_obj, user=me, message=msg)
```

**Django Chat Models**

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    first = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return f'chat_{self.id}'

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="messages")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Django Chat Urls**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import ThreadViewSet, ChatMessageViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('thread', ThreadViewSet)
router.register('chatMessage', ChatMessageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Expected Output**
I was expecting the "CONNECTED" message with the event information printed on the console according to the websocket_connect method in the consumers class. Similarly a "open" message with the event fired in my browser's console from the Angular 2+ chat.component.ts.

**Actual Output**

I immediately get this warning message on the browser console:

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/344/ux0z32ma/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.*

After about 2 minutes of waiting...
[Attached image shows what is automatically output on the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cOqa.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have missed something, because I cannot see the Django configuration, but as far as I understood, you wrote that you're running the frontend and backend server separately. You can see that the frontend is trying to establish the connection to `localhost:4200`. I belive that is the angular server which doesn't make sense, you should point your WebSocket to the Django app, so in my opinion you should modify the method below:

```
SERVER_URL = "localhost:8000"

getEndpoint() {
  let wsStart = "ws://"
  if (window.location.protocol == "https:") {
    wsStart = 'wss://'
  }
  this.endpoint = wsStart + SERVER_URL + window.location.pathname;
  return this.endpoint;
}
```

But if you're hosting both apps on Django and exposing that on port 4200 that doesn't apply, though I'm quite sure that's not your case.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had tried that earlier and tried it again. I got a different error:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/messages/1' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403.

I see! Yes! Earlier both were hosted on localhost:8000, now each is different. Front: :4200 and back-end at 127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: @palebluedot Perfect, glad it did help! If the answer worked for you, I would appreciate if you accepted this as the correct answer. Cheers!

Comment: I got : WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/messages/1' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403. Do you know what might be causing this. At least now I know that the URL, should be the server url

Comment: `AllowedHostsOriginValidator` is using the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` from the Djnago settings. What's your current setup? My guess would be that you need to add the `localhost:4200` host there.

Comment: Ahhhhhh!! I added it in! I think that worked.
Now a routing error: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: No route found for path 'messages/1'.

I originally had "127.0.0.1" in the ALLOWED HOSTS so I had assumed that this is the same as "localhost" so I was under the assumption that I did not need to add anything.
Prior to your response : ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['joole-api.herokuapp.com', '.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']

Comment: @palebluedot I think the issue may be related to the URL regex (`"^messages/(?P<id>[\w.@+-]+)/$`), but at the moment I would just guess blindly. Maybe instead of saying you expect a word, you should say that it's supposed to be a digit? Or make sure in the `ChatConsumer` that the `get_thread` method does not throw an exception in the `id=id` filter. That would be my suspicion - I think you can also cast it explicitly to an `int`.

Comment: I've been at it for a bit! FINALLY CONNECTED! THANKYOU THANKYOU!!!
 
This routing worked..........path('messages/<int:pk>', ChatConsumer)